# proftpd: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, proftpd, plesk

If I try to connect to my proftpd server these errors will be logged in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Dec 29 03:22:38 ****** proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session opened for user ****** by (uid=0)
Dec 29 03:22:59 ****** proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session opened for user ****** by (uid=0)
Dec 29 03:24:49 ****** proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session closed for user ******
Dec 29 03:24:49 ****** proftpd: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
Dec 29 03:25:09 ****** proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session closed for user ******
Dec 29 03:25:09 ****** proftpd: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
sudo update-rc.d dbus defaults
sudo service dbus restart
/etc/init.d/xinetd stop
/etc/init.d/xinetd start
```

Executing `sudo service dbus restart` doesn't work:

```
Failed to restart dbus.service: Operation refused, unit dbus.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status dbus.service' for details.
```

What would you recommend? I cannot connect to the proftpd server.

Comment: Questions involving Plesk (and other web hosting control panels) are considered off-topic for serverfault. [You may find help here.](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8095/472047)

Comment: The question is about proftpd, not Plesk.

Comment: It's got a `plesk` tag and a quick search of the error message shows that mostly plesk users seem to be affected by this.

Comment: This is like going to a hospital to seek help and they reject you because you are black. We’re discussing server issues here, so what does it matter if Plesk is involved? If you want to report the question for being in the wrong place, then do it. I think I need to go to college and get a phd title in order to use Stack.

Comment: I think it's rather like having a broken arm and going to a cardiologist, who then sends you to a orthopedist :-D - this issue has been discussed here _really_ a lot, see my link!

Comment: @digijay where had it been discussed?

Comment: Particularly here: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels

Comment: Anyway, I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

In Plesk:

**Cause**

Access to the server over SSH is set to Forbidden in Domains > example.com > Web Hosting Access.

**Solution**

1. Log into Plesk
2. Navigate to Plesk > Domains > example.com > Web Hosting Access
3. Make sure that the field Access to the server over SSH is set to any available shell (but not to Forbidden).
4. For example, set /bin/sh

[Source](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000065009-Unable-to-connect-to-Plesk-via-SFTP-Authentication-failed-Failed-to-connect-to-system-bus-Permission-denied)